# Non-trivial nested environment expansions with lualatex dependent packages

Tags: macros, luatex, environments, expansion, lilypond

In the following MWE I have an environment that needs `lualatex` to compile.

In brief, I'm trying to create an environment that creates a very specific instance of another environment, i.e. with a bunch of default code templated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}         % can exclude expl3, xparse loads it
\usepackage{xpatch}         % can exclude etoolbox, xpatch loads it

\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage[program=lilypond]{lyluatex}


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\tune}{}
{%
    \begin{lilypond}
    % templated code will go here
}
\def\endtune
{%
    % templated code will go here
    \end{lilypond}
}

% this structure doesn't work either when identical code is inserted
%\NewDocumentEnvironment{tune}{} 
%{%
%}
%{% 
%}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tune}
        c'4 d' e' f' g' a' b' c''
    \end{tune}

\end{document}
```

I know not many will have lyluatex or lilypond installed, and I know this problem isn't reproducible with every kind of nested environments (i.e. replace lilypond with itemize or figure, etc. and this will work fine), but I think I've got an expansion problem which this particular environment is sensitive to.

When I run the above MWE I get the following errors:

`%\begin{lilypond} on input line 28 ended by \end{tune}. \end{tune}`

`%\begin{tune} on input line 28 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}`

which is telling me, that `\end{tune}` isn't being expanded in time to prove that `\end{lilypond}` actually exists.

> If I'm right, my question is:
>
> **Can I force this expansion somehow?**

This simple example will successfully compile if the complete environment is within the macro/command, which I think confirms that there's an expansion problem with the end part.  Note:  I say this simple example is successful because I've seen questions warning that lilypond commands with square brackets nested in a latex macro have difficulties.  I have not explored this as I don't yet have a working modular environment to explore with.

I also suspect that the extra scripting execution layer may be part of the problem, but I'm brand new to lua, and have just started reading some introductory level material.

**EDIT**

As it also appears that the complexity of the lilypond code will affect the approach, here is a sample lilypond block that successfully compiles in latex with lyluatex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}         % can exclude expl3, xparse loads it
\usepackage{xpatch}         % can exclude etoolbox, xpatch loads it

\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage[program=lilypond]{lyluatex}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{lilypond}
    \version "2.16"
    \language "français"

    \header {
        tagline = ""
        composer = ""
    }

    MetriqueArmure = {
        \tempo 4=70
        \time 3/4
        \key do \major
    }

    italique = { \override Score . LyricText #'font-shape = #'italic }

    roman = { \override Score . LyricText #'font-shape = #'roman }

    MusiqueTheme = \relative do' {
        \partial 4 do4
        fa4 fa la
        fa4 fa la
        sol4 sol la8[( sol])
        fa2 do4
        fa4 fa la
        fa4 fa la
        sol4 sol la8[( sol])
        fa2 \breathe fa4^"Refrain"
        sib2 sib4
        la2 la4
        sol4 sol sol
        do2 la4
        sib2 sib4
        la2 la4
        sol4 sol la8[( sol])
        fa2. \bar "|."
    }

    Paroles = \lyricmode {
        L'heure e -- tait ve -- nu -- e,
        ou l'ai -- rain sa -- cre,
        de sa voix con -- nu -- e,
        an -- non -- cait l'A -- ve.

        \italique
        A -- ve, a -- ve, a -- ve Ma -- ri -- a_!
        A -- ve, a -- ve, a -- ve Ma -- ri -- a_!
    }

    \score{
        <<
        \new Staff <<
        \set Staff.midiInstrument = "flute"
        \set Staff.autoBeaming = ##f
        \new Voice = "theme" {
            \override Score.PaperColumn #'keep-inside-line = ##t
            \MetriqueArmure
            \MusiqueTheme
        }
        >>
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto theme {
            \Paroles
        }
        >>
        \layout{}
        \midi{}
    }
\end{lilypond} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lilypond` environment uses LuaTeX callbacks to grab its contents.  Inside the `\lilypond` command there is a switch which lets it act as an environment *or* as a command depending on how it is called.   This screws thing up for you here.  Instead you can simply use the low level commands `\ly` and `\endly` which `\lilypond` uses under the hood.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xparse}         % can exclude expl3, xparse loads it
\usepackage{xpatch}         % can exclude etoolbox, xpatch loads it

\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage[program=lilypond]{lyluatex}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tune}{}{\ly}{\endly}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tune}
        c'4 d' e' f' g' a' b' c''
    \end{tune}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a rapid answer!  This is really really neat.  What kind of limitations will there be for the contents of BODY or within the templated sections that will surround BODY. I pulled a more complex example from the lyluatex test.tex page and saw that this extra level of complexity resulted in `Undefined Control Sequence` Errors.  I still have a ways to go in troubleshooting down to the exact syntax bits that cause the failure.  There's no shortage of possibilities I anticipate, seeing how lilypond uses `<<>>` encapsulations and `\score, \midi{}, \layout{}` type commands.

Comment: @EngBIRD Actually my answer was just wrong.  Please see the updated answer for a working and robust solution.

Comment: Thanks, This is really handy information about the under the hood code. It indeed works for even the more complex example I updated my question with. In playing around with moving code to the template area, I've noticed that special character sequences, based on `#` in particular will cause problems because they are expected to be used when providing arguments, which I will likely want to preserve.  I'll play around with catcode and input/include commands to see if any of these provide an easy fix, but your answer takes care of the hard part.  THANKS!

Comment: Because I originally thought that my question was generic, and wouldn't have a `lilypond` based solution, if you want to include a second answer with your `environ` package information, I would also upvote that one as well. It contained useful information that could get hits from the broader question title.